# Microsoft Word Docx Download Attachment Error

Tags: docx, docx4j

I have doc or docx document saved in Unix directory and integrate with web page which allow user to download the attachment. I have following code to stream the character and saves as Word document with correct MIME type but why when open it shows garbage character. It is relate to character encoding problem. How to solve this? Should I use docx4j?

```
String fullfilename = filename;

        File f = new File(fullfilename);
        int length = 0;

        ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();
        ServletContext context = getContext();
        String mimetype = context.getMimeType(fullfilename);

        response.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype
                : "application/x-download");
        response.setContentLength((int) f.length());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
                + filename);

        byte[] bbuf = new byte[fullfilename.length()];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
            op.write(bbuf, 0, length);

        }

        in.close();
        op.flush();
        op.close();
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: docx4j is not relevant unless you need to create or modify the docx

Comment: what mime types are you using, and what is the client browser and OS showing the garbage?

Comment: The mime type use to create the file is application/msword. Browser is Mozilla Firefox. Thanks. Please help.

Comment: Add an application which handles the mime type. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf

Comment: For a docx, you should use application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the correct mime type resolved the issue.